# NPM 9.4.0 FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, npm, out-of-memory, heap-memory

`npm install` runs into the following core dump:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[112733:0x6df42a0]  5902114 ms: Scavenge 4014.3 (4125.8) -> 3997.8 (4124.9) MB, 5.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.385, current mu = 0.442) allocation failure; 
[112733:0x6df42a0]  5902128 ms: Scavenge 4014.3 (4125.8) -> 3998.6 (4125.8) MB, 5.1 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.385, current mu = 0.442) allocation failure; 
[112733:0x6df42a0]  5902211 ms: Scavenge 4013.8 (4126.6) -> 3998.7 (4125.8) MB, 5.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.385, current mu = 0.442) task; 


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xbe3c50 node::Abort() [npm i]
 2: 0xaf08b4  [npm i]
 3: 0xdcf7c0 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [npm i]
 4: 0xdcfb76 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [npm i]
 5: 0xfce5f5  [npm i]
 6: 0xfceba6 v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [npm i]
 7: 0xfe0e96  [npm i]
 8: 0xfe1ad5 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [npm i]
 9: 0xfbda8f v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithLightRetrySlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [npm i]
10: 0xfbead7 v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [npm i]
11: 0xf9e23a v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [npm i]
12: 0x13b1b6f v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [npm i]
13: 0x18383f9  [npm i]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

```
$ npm --version
9.4.0
$ node --version
v19.6.0
```

Comment: So what's in your dependency list that triggers the out of memory error? Also note that the current Node is 19.8.1, which comes with npm 9.5.1, so you'll also want to update your Node in case you're hitting an NPM bug that already got fixed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75764390/npm-9-5-1-npm-install-runs-into-gyp-error

Comment: Time to delete this post. But also: time to actually update your dependencies, because your new question's log shows you're some truly ancient libraries that you should absolutely not be using with Node 19 (or Node 14, for that matter).