# Can't run any NPM 9.6.4 command at all. They all run into `gyp error`

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-gyp

```
$ n doctor
Check                               Value   Recommendation/Notes
npm ping                            ok       
npm -v                              ok      current: v9.6.4, latest: v9.6.4
node -v                             ok      current: v19.8.1, recommended: v19.8.1
npm config get registry             ok      using default registry (https://registry.npmjs.org/)
git executable in PATH              ok      /usr/bin/git
global bin folder in PATH           ok      /usr/local/bin
Perms check on cached files         ok       
Perms check on local node_modules   ok       
Perms check on global node_modules  ok       
Perms check on local bin folder     ok       
Perms check on global bin folder    ok       
npm WARN verifyCachedFiles Content garbage-collected: 162 (72726571 bytes)
npm WARN verifyCachedFiles Cache issues have been fixed
Verify cache contents               ok      verified 15972 tarballs
```

```
$ n i
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'core@1.0.113',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '0.6 || 0.8' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v19.8.1', npm: '9.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'core@1.0.113',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '0.6 || 0.8' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v19.8.1', npm: '9.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated formidable@1.2.6: Please upgrade to latest, formidable@v2 or formidable@v3! Check these notes: https://
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated coffee-script@1.12.7: CoffeeScript on NPM has moved to "coffeescript" (no hyphen)
npm WARN deprecated superagent@3.8.3: Please upgrade to v7.0.2+ of superagent.  We have fixed numerous issues with streams, form-data, attach(), filesystem errors not bubbling up (ENOENT on attach()), and all tests are now passing.  See the releases tab for more information at <https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/releases>.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /usr/src/Node.JSRestAPI/src/infrastructure/node_modules/core/node_modules/compress-buffer
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! make: Entering directory '/usr/src/Node.JSRestAPI/src/infrastructure/node_modules/core/node_modules/compress-buffer/build'
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/compress_buffer_bindings/src/compress-buffer.o
npm ERR! make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/Node.JSRestAPI/src/infrastructure/node_modules/core/node_modules/compress-buffer/build'
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@19.8.1 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.7 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/src/Node.JSRestAPI/src/infrastructure/node_modules/core/node_modules/compress-buffer/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/khteh/.cache/node-gyp/19.8.1/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/khteh/.cache/node-gyp/19.8.1',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/khteh/.cache/node-gyp/19.8.1/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/usr/src/Node.JSRestAPI/src/infrastructure/node_modules/core/node_modules/compress-buffer',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! ../src/compress-buffer.cc:23:1: error: ‘Handle’ does not name a type
npm ERR!    23 | Handle<Value> ThrowNodeError(const char* what = NULL) {
npm ERR!       | ^~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/compress-buffer.cc:27:1: error: ‘Handle’ does not name a type
npm ERR!    27 | Handle<Value> compress(const Arguments& args) {
npm ERR!       | ^~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/compress-buffer.cc:97:1: error: ‘Handle’ does not name a type
npm ERR!    97 | Handle<Value> uncompress(const Arguments &args) {
npm ERR!       | ^~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/compress-buffer.cc:183:1: error: variable or field ‘init’ declared void
npm ERR!   183 | init (Handle<Object> target) {
npm ERR!       | ^~~~
npm ERR! ../src/compress-buffer.cc:183:7: error: ‘Handle’ was not declared in this scope
npm ERR!   183 | init (Handle<Object> target) {
npm ERR!       |       ^~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/compress-buffer.cc:183:20: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
npm ERR!   183 | init (Handle<Object> target) {
npm ERR!       |                    ^
npm ERR! ../src/compress-buffer.cc:183:22: error: ‘target’ was not declared in this scope
npm ERR!   183 | init (Handle<Object> target) {
npm ERR!       |                      ^~~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/compress-buffer.cc:1:
npm ERR! ../src/compress-buffer.cc:200:39: error: ‘init’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘int’?
npm ERR!   200 | NODE_MODULE(compress_buffer_bindings, init);
npm ERR!       |                                       ^~~~
npm ERR! /home/khteh/.cache/node-gyp/19.8.1/include/node/node.h:1168:36: note: in definition of macro ‘NODE_MODULE_X’
npm ERR!  1168 |       (node::addon_register_func) (regfunc),                          \
npm ERR!       |                                    ^~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/compress-buffer.cc:200:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘NODE_MODULE’
npm ERR!   200 | NODE_MODULE(compress_buffer_bindings, init);
npm ERR!       | ^~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! make: *** [compress_buffer_bindings.target.mk:111: Release/obj.target/compress_buffer_bindings/src/compress-buffer.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:203:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:512:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:293:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.19.0-35-generic
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /usr/src/Node.JSRestAPI/src/infrastructure/node_modules/core/node_modules/compress-buffer
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v19.8.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/khteh/.npm/_logs/2023-03-17T06_25_22_733Z-debug-0.log
```

```
$ node -v
v19.8.1
$ npm -v
9.6.4
```

Update / upgrade runs into the same errors:

```
$ n outdated
Package          Current  Wanted  Latest  Location  Depended by
@types/morgan    MISSING   1.9.4   1.9.4  -         Node.JSRestAPI
ansi-regex       MISSING   6.0.1   6.0.1  -         Node.JSRestAPI
async            MISSING   3.2.4   3.2.4  -         Node.JSRestAPI
compression      MISSING   1.7.4   1.7.4  -         Node.JSRestAPI
config           MISSING   3.3.9   3.3.9  -         Node.JSRestAPI
cookie-parser    MISSING   1.4.6   1.4.6  -         Node.JSRestAPI
cors             MISSING   2.8.5   2.8.5  -         Node.JSRestAPI
debug            MISSING   4.3.4   4.3.4  -         Node.JSRestAPI
ejs              MISSING   3.1.9   3.1.9  -         Node.JSRestAPI
email-validator  MISSING   2.0.4   2.0.4  -         Node.JSRestAPI
express          MISSING  4.18.2  4.18.2  -         Node.JSRestAPI
helmet           MISSING   6.0.1   6.0.1  -         Node.JSRestAPI
http-errors      MISSING   2.0.0   2.0.0  -         Node.JSRestAPI
morgan           MISSING  1.10.0  1.10.0  -         Node.JSRestAPI
morgan-json      MISSING   1.1.0   1.1.0  -         Node.JSRestAPI
pg               MISSING  8.10.0  8.10.0  -         Node.JSRestAPI
spdy             MISSING   4.0.2   4.0.2  -         Node.JSRestAPI
$ n update -S
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'core@1.0.113',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '0.6 || 0.8' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v19.8.1', npm: '9.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'core@1.0.113',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '0.6 || 0.8' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v19.8.1', npm: '9.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated formidable@1.2.6: Please upgrade to latest, formidable@v2 or formidable@v3! Check these notes: https://
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated coffee-script@1.12.7: CoffeeScript on NPM has moved to "coffeescript" (no hyphen)
npm WARN deprecated superagent@3.8.3: Please upgrade to v7.0.2+ of superagent.  We have fixed numerous issues with streams, form-data, attach(), filesystem errors not bubbling up (ENOENT on attach()), and all tests are now passing.  See the releases tab for more information at <https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/releases>.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /usr/src/Node.JSRestAPI/src/infrastructure/node_modules/core/node_modules/compress-buffer
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! make: Entering directory '/usr/src/Node.JSRestAPI/src/infrastructure/node_modules/core/node_modules/compress-buffer/build'
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/compress_buffer_bindings/src/compress-buffer.o
npm ERR! make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/Node.JSRestAPI/src/infrastructure/node_modules/core/node_modules/compress-buffer/build'
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@19.8.1 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.7 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/src/Node.JSRestAPI/src/infrastructure/node_modules/core/node_modules/compress-buffer/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/khteh/.cache/node-gyp/19.8.1/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/khteh/.cache/node-gyp/19.8.1',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/khteh/.cache/node-gyp/19.8.1/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/usr/src/Node.JSRestAPI/src/infrastructure/node_modules/core/node_modules/compress-buffer',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! ../src/compress-buffer.cc:23:1: error: ‘Handle’ does not name a type
npm ERR!    23 | Handle<Value> ThrowNodeError(const char* what = NULL) {
npm ERR!       | ^~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/compress-buffer.cc:27:1: error: ‘Handle’ does not name a type
npm ERR!    27 | Handle<Value> compress(const Arguments& args) {
npm ERR!       | ^~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/compress-buffer.cc:97:1: error: ‘Handle’ does not name a type
npm ERR!    97 | Handle<Value> uncompress(const Arguments &args) {
npm ERR!       | ^~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/compress-buffer.cc:183:1: error: variable or field ‘init’ declared void
npm ERR!   183 | init (Handle<Object> target) {
npm ERR!       | ^~~~
npm ERR! ../src/compress-buffer.cc:183:7: error: ‘Handle’ was not declared in this scope
npm ERR!   183 | init (Handle<Object> target) {
npm ERR!       |       ^~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/compress-buffer.cc:183:20: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
npm ERR!   183 | init (Handle<Object> target) {
npm ERR!       |                    ^
npm ERR! ../src/compress-buffer.cc:183:22: error: ‘target’ was not declared in this scope
npm ERR!   183 | init (Handle<Object> target) {
npm ERR!       |                      ^~~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/compress-buffer.cc:1:
npm ERR! ../src/compress-buffer.cc:200:39: error: ‘init’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘int’?
npm ERR!   200 | NODE_MODULE(compress_buffer_bindings, init);
npm ERR!       |                                       ^~~~
npm ERR! /home/khteh/.cache/node-gyp/19.8.1/include/node/node.h:1168:36: note: in definition of macro ‘NODE_MODULE_X’
npm ERR!  1168 |       (node::addon_register_func) (regfunc),                          \
npm ERR!       |                                    ^~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/compress-buffer.cc:200:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘NODE_MODULE’
npm ERR!   200 | NODE_MODULE(compress_buffer_bindings, init);
npm ERR!       | ^~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! make: *** [compress_buffer_bindings.target.mk:111: Release/obj.target/compress_buffer_bindings/src/compress-buffer.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:203:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:512:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:293:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.19.0-35-generic
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /usr/src/Node.JSRestAPI/src/infrastructure/node_modules/core/node_modules/compress-buffer
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v19.8.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/khteh/.npm/_logs/2023-03-17T07_11_28_800Z-debug-0.log
```

```
$ n ls core
node.jsrestapi@1.0.0 /usr/src/Node.JSRestAPI
└── (empty)
```

Comment: have you tried to downgrade your node version? try to downgrade your node version and then try to run 'npm i'

Comment: Or upgrade your dependencies: you're using _really old ones_ and you should probably do what the error log telling you with all those "deprecated" notices. Ancient dependencies will have ancient Node versions as supported engines. Your error is for [compress buffer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compress-buffer) which has _the biggest, reddest notice_ to not use it anymore. Now is the time for dependency maintenance.

Comment: I can't do that either. Running `npm update -S` / `npm upgrade -S` runs into the same error.

Comment: I don't have https://www.npmjs.com/package/compress-buffer in my `package.json`. No idea how it gets pulled into the dependency....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into similar issues resolved by the following:

- Running `npm doctor`
- This will probably show npm is outdated so do a `npm update -g`, which will update all the global packages, including npm
- Downgrade to the LTS version of node

What seems strange to me is the `core@1.0.113` requirement, which is not a dependency of anything show from you `npm oudated` output.  That's where the compress_buffer dependency is coming from.  Is there anything else installed globally that can be causing issues - `npm outdated -g`?

Comment: Nothing shows up in `npm outdated -g`.

Comment: So, everything on the global side is up to date.  Can you provide output for `npm ls core`?  This will show what is depending on core.  `npm prune` should clean up anything that should not belong in your `node_modules` folder, and it may get rid the the extraneous dependency.

Comment: Provided in my post.

Comment: The `npm doctor` did fix come cache issues, but I suppose you performed a `npm install` after that?

Comment: Also, the `npm ls core` showed that nothing was depending on `core`, which was expected.  `npm explain core` would show something similar.
I think the `npm prune` will do it, followed by an `npm install`

Comment: I tried to replicate the problem by installing all the dependencies in a codespace with your same environment, and there's no problem with any of your dependencies.  I then forced an install of the `core` package and had exactly the same errors.  As noted previously, `compress-buffer` is where there are issues compiling that package, but it's a dependency of `core` which should not be there.

I would simply try a `npm uninstall core`.  This worked in the codespace.

Comment: I have a `core` in the typescript project workspace. Renaming it to something else fixes the problem. Thanks!